# Cluster disk shows offline , where as I can access the disk from windows explorer

Tags: sql-server, hard-drive, cluster

I have a Log drive on SQL server which I can access the files through windows explorer. The Failover cluster manager shows that the log drive # is offline.

When I try to bring the Cluster Disk# Online, it gives error

"Failed to bring the resource 'Cluster Disk # Online"
Error Code 0x8007174b 
Clustered Sotrage is not connected to the node"